# How to prevent tablesorter static rows from being filtered?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

Given this code, tablesorter will remove my static row from view when the user filters and it meets the criteria for the filter:

```
$('.reportTableData').tablesorter({sortList: [[0, 0]],
        widgets: ['filter', 'stickyHeaders', 'staticRow'],
        widgetOptions: { stickyHeaders_attachTo: $('.wrapper'),
    }
}
```

I have a single static row that appears at the top of the table. However, I want it to stay there even when the user filters via the widget. I've tried `childRows` and spent an extended time working with `filter_functions:` but I believe the static row was never appearing in the filtered list.

Comment: I think you need to include the `static` class name on the row - see docs: https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-static-row.html

Comment: Hey @Mottie! Here's an example of how the static row doesn't persist after the filter. https://jsfiddle.net/fjwqtrnk/ Any ideas for what can be done? Even if it's hacky.

Comment: I ended up just doing this:

`.bind('filterEnd', function(e, filter){ $('#my_static_row').show(); });`